# Same javascript event for different images?

Tags: javascript, hover

I have an image that when hover, a div with an overlay will fade in and out.

```
<div id="img-one">
    <div id="overlay-one">
          <div class="card-overlay-text">
              <p>Enlarge Image<p></div>
         </div>
    <img src="assets/img/card_one.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

However, I have multiple images and I need to repeat this code for each of these images (assigned with different div's id). How can I get, when hover on specific image.

The code only run on individual image only?

```
$(function() {
   $('#img-one').hover(function() { 
     $('#overlay-one').stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
   }, function() { 
     $('#overlay-one').stop(true,true).fadeOut(); 
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use general class in all the image containers `div`'s and overlay `div`'s, like :

```
<div id="img-one" class='img-container'>
    <div id="overlay-one" class='overlay'>
         ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Then adjust you JS code to invoke just related `overlay` :

```
$(function() {
   $('.img-container').hover(function() { 
     $('.overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
   }, function() { 
     $('.overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(); 
   });
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.img-container').hover(function() { 
    $('.overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
  }, function() { 
    $('.overlay', this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(); 
  });
});
```

```css
.img-container{
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='img-container'>
  <div class='overlay'>
    <div class="card-overlay-text">
      <p>Enlarge Image 1<p></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <div class='overlay'>
    <div class="card-overlay-text">
      <p>Enlarge Image 2<p></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='img-container'>
  <div class='overlay'>
    <div class="card-overlay-text">
      <p>Enlarge Image 3<p></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll better use classes. Then do something like this:

```
$('.main-container').find('.div-class-name').forEach(function(el) {
    <bind a handler for each consequent element here>
});
```

You'll end up with a bunch of handlers that are bound to each individual ".div-class-name" element.

Comment: `$('.main-container').find('.div-class-name').forEach` is same as `$('.main-container .div-class-name').hover`?

Comment: OP wants to bind individual handlers to each '.div-class-name'.

Comment: `('.class-name').on('click', myFunc)` attaches the event handler to each element with class `class-name`. jQuery does that automatically, no need for `forEach`

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use `classes` because that is what classes are for and id's are not.

If your case demands some situation where you have no control over the HTML part, you can use wildcards in attribute selectors in some cases. Like `div[id^=overlay]` to selects all `div` with `id` starting with `overlay`

```js
$(function() {
   $('div[id^=img]').hover(function() { 
     $('div[id^=overlay]',this).stop(true,true).fadeIn(); 
   }, function() { 
     $('div[id^=overlay]',this).stop(true,true).fadeOut(); 
   });
});
```

```css
div[id^=img]{
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:1px solid black;
  margin:2px;
  }

div[id^=img] > div[id^=overlay]{
  position:absolute;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  display:none;
  width:100px;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img-one">
    <div id="overlay-one">
          <div class="card-overlay-text">
              <p>Enlarge Image 1<p></div>
         </div>
    <img width="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Raff_House.jpg" alt="" />
</div>

<div id="img-two">
    <div id="overlay-two">
          <div class="card-overlay-text">
              <p>Enlarge Image 2<p></div>
         </div>
    <img width="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Raff_House.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the jQuery Easy Overlay Plugin
http://eivissapp.github.io/jquery-easy-overlay/

In the code, you should assign a class to the images, and call this statement (that will work for each image):

```
jQuery("img.yourclass").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).easyOverlay("start");
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).easyOverlay("stop");
});
```

If you have fontawesome in the page, then execute this before the code above (otherwhise the plugin will use the fontawesome spinner inside the overlay div):

```
jQuery.fn.easyOverlay.options = { spin: false }
```